# Why am I not able to block a site in CCProxy server?

Tags: proxy, firewall, socks-proxy, proxy-server, web-filtering

I have installed CCProxy server and have setup Firefox to use this proxy server. Now I am trying out different features of proxy server.

For testing purpose, I want to check blocking of `stackoverflow.com` site. I create a webfilter and edit the client account to use this web filter. Still, I can access this site.

Filter snapshot is:

[image]

Account snapshot is:

[image]

And I know that requests are going thru proxy because my accesses are reflected in monitor tab. And I don't think that it is because of caching, because I am able to ask questions etc… as well. And I have restarted the proxy after configuration.

Comment: I haven't used this program before but the usage for `Forbidden URL` suggests that you should be putting something other than `http://` in there. So try leaving that blank, and making sure the user is definitely coming in through `192.168.2.75`

Comment: @todda : ok, I left it as blank but still I can access the site.

Comment: Also, I assume that applying the web filter is literally a FILTER onto this rule. But your rule doesn't block anything? `Maximum Connections: -1` is equal to unlimited connections.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me by specifying a text file in the site filter field (instead of the site directly in the field like you have it).

Then inside of the text file you list out your desired blocked sites. One per line. Semicolon at end of the site name.

Example:

Point site filter field at `C:\blacklist.txt`

Inside `blacklist.txt` have the following

```
*.facebook.com;
*.youtube.com;
*.netflix.com;
```